# Open a new box/window on selecting a particular value

Tags: html, css

I have a list of users that is generated dynamically.

```
$sql0="SELECT * FROM users";
$result0 = mysqli_query($con,$sql0);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result0)>0)
    {
        while($row0=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result0))
            {   
                echo $row0['name'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
    }
```

The o/p would contain list of users 
eg:

```
user_one
user_two
user_three
```

What i want is that if i click on any one user from the above list a chat window should get opened (as it is being done in many sites nowadays) i have a window created here [@fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/nmrhLpn9/). but what i am not able to do is that

i wish to carry the userid of the selected user to this new window and display the data related to that selected user, such as name, image etc .

And i wish to fix the chat box to the end of the screen as it is done in fb, so that the user can open multiple boxes

can anyone please tell how it can be done

Comment: You have to pass userId and all things related to that html from your php file, can you tell me which framework you used?

Comment: @Harsh Sanghani i am using bootstrap for front end

Comment: ok and for back  end?

Comment: @Harsh Sanghani the entire page is built in bootstrap and core php

Comment: ok then when you open your chat window at that time make a ajax call which get all user information from your php file and just set them in your window.

Comment: @Harsh Sanghani can u also please tell me how i can fix the chat box to the end of the screen(as done in facebook)

Answer (score 0):

You can add following css to fix chat window at end of screen :-

```
.panel-primary 
{
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
}
```

It may help you.